# Socket close while recv issue

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu, thrift

Ubuntu 14.04. If `recv()` is blocked waiting for data on an open connection, `close()` or `shutdown()`, called from another thread, didn't cause `recv()` to return until after the peer closed the connection.

How can I unblock the `recv()`?

I found this behavior inside TServerSocket class from thrift.

Comment: are the keep alive and so linger options of socket set? Can you try unsetting them?

Comment: What does 'didn't force `recv()` return until connection open' mean? What is your question? @fayyazki What exactly do those options have to do with it?

Comment: I expect that recv will return after I called close on socket.

Comment: There was only disabling of linger option. I tried to comment it, but this didst change behavior.

Comment: You don't need to disable the linger option. It is off by default, and best left that way. The suggestion about keepalive is equally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is most unclear, but if you want to unblock a `recv()` before closing the socket in another thread, the best technique is to shutdown the socket for input before the close. That will cause `recv()` to return zero as though the peer had closed the connection.

Comment: Neither shutdown or close didn't unblock the recv(). It unblocks after connection closing by client.

Comment: Did you shut it down *for input*?